# IO handler for a file

Tags: file, io

is it possible to create a file that :

1- when a program tries to read from it

2- a program i made sends it the data as if it was "reading from a normal file"

my idea is to have some sort of image file that when opened my program gets a random image from the internet and for the program which opened the file it appears like its reading from a normal file

also the extension must be the same as any image file extension (.png , .jpeg etc)

another example :

the file "hello.png"

i- i open it

2- a cat picture appears!

3- i open it again

4- a dog picture appears and its the same "hello.png"

5- i use a program to open the image "example GIMP"

6- a flower picture appears

etc

i tried looking for an answer but i couldn't really find what i was looking for

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: One possibility is a UNIX named socket.  Google it and see if this is what you need.